# Running bash script using gnu parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have my script using `while read` to process some file line by line..

When I do:

```
head -n5 file1 | ./myscript.sh
```

I get my results well.

But trying to parallelize it using gnu `parallel`:

```
head -n5 file1 | parallel -j 4 ./myscript.sh
```

yields `result` file empty!?

I tried also with:

```
parallel -j 4 -a file1 ./myscript.sh
```

but still doesn't work. I was trying to do similar to what they say in
documentation, but without any success.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Maybe this can help:

```
head -n5 file1 | parallel -a - -j 4 echo #this works
head -n5 file1 | parallel -a - -j 4 ./myscript #this doesn't
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parallel` doesn't send the lines of input to `stdin` of the command given to it, but appends the line to the command you give.

If you write it like you have, then you're effectively calling `./myscript.sh <INPUT>`, where you want to call `./myscript.sh`, and send the input as `stdin`.

This should work:

```
head -n5 file1 | parallel -j 4 "echo {} | ./myscript.sh"
```

The `{}` indicates to `parallel` where you want the input to go, rather than the default of at the end.

Comment: If the script is writing to a results file then it might be overwriting it each time. You need to make it append to the file instead. `parallel` will create a new instance of your script for each of the input lines.

Comment: you were right about append, but now my counter in file stays on 1 for each increment in line, because all of those isolated processes :), anyway could you explain the situation on my edit above?

Comment: I don't know what counter you mean; what does the script do? `echo <SOMETHING>` outputs `<SOMETHING>`, so the first of your examples should print each line to `stdout`. Your script needs the input to be sent on `stdin` though, rather than as an argument.

Comment: ok now parallel is working, but I get repeated and erroneous results, as in my script I am doing matches on words from one file, onto another big file via `grep`, isn't it supposed to take care of splitting files into chunks per process so that they are not mixed?

Comment: Each instance of the script will be given only one line as input. I don't really understand what you're trying to do with this script. Could you post it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89957/discussion-between-branquito-and-gandaliter).

Answer (score 5):

--pipe is made for you:

```
cat file1 | parallel --pipe -N5 ./myscript.sh
```

But you need to change `myscript.sh` so it does not save to `result` but instead print the output to stdout. Then you can:

```
cat file1 | parallel --pipe -N5 ./myscript.sh > result
```

and avoid any mixing.